# Fabricjs objectCaching: zoom image content, keep image border

Tags: javascript, image, zooming, fabricjs

I try to implement image zooming with fabricjs. My requirement: zooming content of image without changing border size (not scaling image).

This is my code: [jsfiddle.net/63twbox/11/](https://jsfiddle.net/Jacky88/c63twbox/11/)

Follow this way I need to set objectCaching of rect to false. But It cause the heavy performance problem when moving image. So I set objectCaching to false in zoom mode and true in other modes. Then I got another problem that after zooming image, change objectCaching between true and false make the content of image changed.

How to keep image content same when changing objectCaching ?

Answer (score 2):

The way you chose to display the image as zoomed is very heavy.
There are faster way that do not require all this drawings.

You solution involves create a pattern on a new canvas.
Canvas creation
draw image on the canvas
pattern creation
draw rect with cache

This is a simpler solution that does not involve patterns or caching.

It consist in rewriting the fabric.Image render method to behave differently using a custom zoomLevel property and the full signature of ctx.drawImage()

```js
fabric.Image.prototype._render = function(ctx) {
  var fwidth = this._element.width / (this.zoomLevel + 1);
  var fheight = this._element.height / (this.zoomLevel + 1);
  var wdiff = (fwidth - this._element.width) / 2;
  var hdiff = (fheight - this._element.height) / 2;
  ctx.drawImage(this._element, -wdiff, -hdiff, fwidth, fheight, -this.width/2, - this.height/2, this.width, this.height);
}
      var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
      fabric.Image.fromURL("https://images2.alphacoders.com/147/147320.png", function(img) {
        var zoomLevel = 0;
        var zoomLevelMin = 0;
        var zoomLevelMax = 3;
        img.zoomLevel = 0
        img.scale(0.1);

        canvas.add(img);
        
        img.zoomIn = function() {
          if (zoomLevel < zoomLevelMax) {
            zoomLevel += 0.1;
            img.zoomLevel = zoomLevel;
          }
        };


        img.zoomOut = function() {
          zoomLevel -= 0.1;
          if (zoomLevel < 0) zoomLevel = 0;
          if (zoomLevel >= zoomLevelMin) {
            img.zoomLevel = zoomLevel;
          }
        };

      });

      canvas.on('mouse:wheel', function(option) {
        var imgObj = canvas.getActiveObject();
        if (!imgObj) return;
        option.e.preventDefault();
        if (option.e.deltaY > 0) {
          imgObj.zoomOut();
        } else {
          imgObj.zoomIn();
        }
        canvas.renderAll();
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.17/fabric.js"></script>
<h1> FabricJS imageHelper</h1>
<div id="canvasContainer">
  <canvas id="c" width="1920" height="600"></canvas>
</div>
<br>
```

Comment: It don't resolve my problem. But it is simpler and faster than my implementation. Great ! Thank @AndreaBogazzi so much.

Comment: so i probably did not get your problem. Can you explain it better?

Comment: thanks, i found this extremely useful. Just wanted to ask, is it possible to PAN Image once its zoomed in. any ideas. how. specially with shift or middle click. that would make it perfect for quick framing of image.

Comment: i think that with latest fabric you can just use crop functionality that should do this. allow you to select a portion of the image.